# Javascript calculate quantity * price

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I'm trying to multiply the quantity and the price for each item for calculating the total, but I'm getting an error in my alert.

```
$.each(data.items, function(index, d){
    var calcultest = d.price * d.qty;
    alert(calcultest)
});
```

Comment: you are missing `)` to close that each

Comment: oh yeah exactly, but it's not the error, i think i forgot something for my var.

Comment: Can you post a sample of data.items?

Comment: `i'm getting an error in my alert` what is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` to convert string to Float

```
$.each(data.items, function(index, d){
    var Price = d.price.replace(",",".");
    var calcultest = parseFloat(Price) * parseFloat(d.qty);
    alert(calcultest.toString().replace(".",","));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/999F3/1/)

Comment: Thanks but i'm getting 209 for example if my price is 11,58 and the qty 19... The correct answer is 220,02. Wy i'm getting 209 ??? Because of the comma ?

Comment: there is `,` in your first no. `parseInt` only select the first no. in your string

Comment: `11*19=209` remove the `,` and try

Comment: Oh ok, i want to keep the , (i don't want to show a total which will be like this : 220.02 (i want 220,02). How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 $.each(data.items, function(index, d){
        var Price = d.price;
        Price = Price.replace(",",".");
        var calcultest = parseInt(Price) * parseInt(d.qty);            
        alert(calcultest);
 });
```

Comment: you're close i'm getting 22002 and i want to get 222,02 !

Comment: TypeError: calcultest.replace is not a function
calcultest  = calcultest.replace(".",","); :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create simple calculators with Javascript I would recommend you to take a look at “Appizy”.

It converts instantly a spreadsheet into a standalone web calculation tool (HTML+CSS+JAVASCRIPT). You don’t need to hardcode the whole interface and calculation formulas!

Just create your working calculator with Open- or LibreOffice and then use Appizy.

I hope it can help. Best,
Nicolas