# How to use Jquery with html helpers of Asp.Net Mvc Core 2.2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using Asp.net mvc core 2.2
the calculations below works fine when I try in jsfiddle.net however the calculation is not working, do nothing as it displays "0.00" when I try in Visual Studio.

1. reference links exist I checked
2. I included scripts in the same view

My view codes:

Code starts here- table class="tbl table table-striped">

```
TABLE HEADERS

     @{ foreach (var item in Model.Tblstsabit)
      {

      <tr style="padding:50px;">
       <td style="text-align:center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.StokKodu)
       </td>
       <td style="text-align:center">
       @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.StokAdi)
       </td>
       <td style="text-align:center">
       @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.SatisFiat1, new { @class = "unitprc" })
        @*for this part I tried <input type="text" class="unitprc"> it works in jsfiddle.net but not in VS*@
       </td>
       <td style="text-align:center;">
       <input type="text" class="qtt" />
       </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="number" max="100" class="col-9" />
        </td>
         <td style="text-align:center;">
          <input type="number" max="100" class="col-9" />
       </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
       <input type="text" readonly value="0.00" class="sum" />
       </td>
       <td style="text-align:center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-stokkodu="@item.StokKodu">
        <img src="~/resimler/garbage.png" />
       </button>
         </td>
       </tr>
   }
}
```

---

Total Sum:

```
<div class="col-4">
<label>Total Sum</label>
<input id="gsum" value="0.00" readonly />
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(".tbl").on("change keyup keydown paste propertychange bind mouseover", function () {
        calculateSum();
    });

    // function    
    function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".sum").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {

    var quantity = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.qtt:text").val();
    var valor = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.unitprc:text").val();

    var subTot = (quantity * valor);

    $(this).val(subTot.toFixed(2));

    sum += parseFloat(subTot.toFixed(2));
            }
        });
        $('#gsum').val(sum.toFixed(2));

    }
</script>
```

I have been looking these codes about 9 hours and couldnt find any reason why it is not working.
Can Foreach loop be the reason?
PS: If you are going to try in jsfiddle.net you should write the code between table tag which has a "cls" named class

Comment: _"the calculation is not working when I try in Visual Studio"_ - What does _"is not working"_ mean? Wrong result? Is the script not executed? Any error messages? ...

Comment: Do nothing. showing "0.00"

Comment: The *Results* section does not correspond to your ASP code. It has "Total Sum", which does not appear in your ASP, but it omits all the `table`, `tr` and `td` tags, that *are* in your ASP code. Could you complete that part of your question?

Comment: @trincot Hi. Total sum section is at the botton section just shows the sum of all ‘sum’s and it doesnt need to be in the table or elsewhere “function calculatesum()” finds it by id ‘#gsum’. Btw code is alittle long and before that ‘sum’ in the rows arent working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the following changes

1. In the view code , add `class = "unitprc"` to the `<td></td>` where `@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.SatisFiat1, new { @class = "unitprc" })` is located , like below

   ```
   <td style="text-align:center" class = "unitprc">
      @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.SatisFiat1)
    </td>
   ```

2.Make some changes in your jquery like below

```
$("input.qtt:text").on("change paste keyup" ,function () {
            calculateSum();
        });

        // function
        function calculateSum() {
            var sum = 0;
            $(".sum").each(function () {
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {

                    var quantity = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.qtt:text").val();
                    var valor = $(this).closest("tr").find(".unitprc").html();

                    var subTot = (quantity * valor);

                    $(this).val(subTot.toFixed(2));

                    sum += parseFloat(subTot.toFixed(2));
                }
            });
            $('#gsum').val(sum.toFixed(2));

        }
```

How it works

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked :)). One last thing though. because of cultural difference the price uses "," instead of "." for example "370,23" that gives "NaN" for the sum. Do you know anyway to handle it

Comment: @Mayk , in your function calculateSum() , you could use **".replace(",",".")"** at the end of ` var valor = $(this).closest("tr").find(".unitprc").html() ` to change the format of the price . Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075595/javascript-calculate-quantity-price

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is returning a STRING. You need to turn it into a number:

```
var quantity = parseFloat($(this).closest("tr").find("input.qtt:text").val());
```